# spark dataset filter column with conditions like pandas

Tags: scala, pandas, apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-ml

I am new to Spark/Scala. i do not know how to use spark dataset to filter columns like pandas.loc.

pandas code:

```
data_fact = pd.read_excel(path, sheetname=sheetname_factor)
//drop some columns which have too many null value
data_fact_v1=data_fact.loc[:,((data_fact>0).sum()>len(data_fact) *0.7)]
```

Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a RDD for this because the API is more flexible. In the following code, I map each row to a list of tuple2 with the column name associated to 0 if the value of the field is null, 1 otherwise. Then I flatten everything and count the number of non null values per column with `reduceByKey`. I finally drop the columns that do not match your requirements in the original dataframe.

```
var data = ...
val cols = data.columns
val total = data.count

val nullMap = data.rdd
    .flatMap{row => cols.filter(col => row.getAs(col) == null).map(col => (col, 1) ) }
    .reduceByKey(_+_)
    .collectAsMap

for(col <- cols) 
    if(nullMap.getOrElse(col, 0).toDouble / total < 0.7)
        data = data.drop(col)
```

**Edit** other method: to avoid flattening the data, you can use the aggregate function

```
def combine(map1 : Map[String, Int], map2 : Map[String, Int]) = 
    map1.keySet
        .union(map2.keySet)
        .map(k => (k, map1.getOrElse(k, 0)+map2.getOrElse(k, 0)))
        .toMap

val nullMap = data.rdd.aggregate(Map[String, Int]())(
     (map, row)=> combine(map, cols.filter(col => row.getAs(col) == null).map(col => (col, 1)).toMap),
     combine)
```

And then the same

```
for(col <- cols) 
    if(nullMap.getOrElse(col, 0).toDouble / total >= 0.3)
        data = data.drop(col)
```

Or

```
val valid_columns = cols
    .filter(col => nullMap.getOrElse(col, 0).toDouble / total >= 0.3)
data = data.drop(valid_columns : _*)
```

Comment: it works，but  low efficiency.it spend 15min.
my test data have 3000 rows and 1000 columns.
cuz pandas is very fast to handle this , Is there a more effective way for spark？

Comment: I edited the code to speed up things. I only flatten null values. Yet 15 minutes for such a small dataset does seem huge. What config are you using?

Comment: I added another method that avoids the flattening altogether (the 1st edit only was only reducing it). Let us know if you still have performance issues.

Comment: I debug the code, find that： data = data.drop(col)  takes up most of the time. because I drop 950 columns from 1000 columns.

Comment: I added a version that only calls drop once. It would be very interesting to know if it gets better now...

Comment: I use this code : data = data.drop(valid_columns : _*)
it spend 36 s！！！ thank you very much. 
tks Oli

Comment: Good to know that repetitive calls to drop are very slow. I would have thought that they would be applied together anyway by spark's optimizer...

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the columns of you dataframe and remove the one with to many null values.

```
val cols = data.columns
val limit = data.count * 0.7

for(mycol <- cols){
   if (data.filter(col(mycol).isNotNull).count < limit){
       data = data.drop(mycol)
   }
}
```

Comment: Your approach works but will generate one task per column which could expensive.